# Ho do i use/display these Categories in an ion select

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to populate an ion select with categories from an API,
this is the object i am getting
[image: Category data]
 but i am having trouble getting the categories exclusively, 
i'm either getting undefined or not getting an array, maybe my interface is wrong

```
export interface CategoryData {
 contents: QuoteCategory[];
```

}

```
export interface QuoteCategory {
 art: string;
 funny: string;
 inspire: string;
 life: string;
 love: string;
 management: string;
 sports: string;
 students: string;
```

}

this is how i subscribe to the function

```
  getCats() {
this.api.getCategories().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue in the interface definition. The `categories` property from the API is a plain object, not an array. So you could try something like the following

```js
export interface QuoteCategories {
  art: string;
  funny: string;
  inspire: string;
  life: string;
  love: string;
  management: string;
  sports: string;
  students: string;
}
```

And you could use it like

service

```js
getCategories(): Observable<QuoteCategories> {
  this.http.get('url').pipe(map(response => response['contents']['categories']));
}
```

component

```js
categories: QuoteCategories;

getCats() {
  this.api.getCategories().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.categories = data;
      console.log(data);
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
    }
  );
}
```

**Update**

`ngFor` can loop only through collections like arrays. You have two options

**1. Using `keyvalue` pipe**

```html
<div *ngFor="let category of categories | keyvalue">
  <span>{{ category.key }} - {{ category.value }}</span>
</div>
```

**2. Access properties directly**

```html
<span>{{ categories.art }}</span>
<span>{{ categories.funny }}</span>
<span>{{ categories.inspire }}</span>
<span>{{ categories.life }}</span>
<span>{{ categories.love }}</span>
<span>{{ categories.management }}</span>
<span>{{ categories.sports }}</span>
<span>{{ categories.students }}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, i have been able to do this and now when i try to populate the ion select with an ngFor i am getting this error "RROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."